# Why does the blue bar overlap in the menu?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenuitem

I have a Problem with my JMenu in Java. When I add a submenu overlaps the blue bar from the menu the submenu.(As you can see in the picture) I habe no idear how I can fix this and I found nothing in the internet.
I hope you can help me.

Example picture:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4SrP.png]

PS: I use the Windows 10 Look and Feel

```
public JFrame frame;
public static JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();


/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Systemstammdaten() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            desktopPane.setBounds(0, 22, frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight());
        }
    });
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 895, 593);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    menuBar.setBounds(0, 0, 3860, 21);

    frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar);

    JMenu mnBearbeiten = new JMenu("Bearbeiten");
    menuBar.add(mnBearbeiten);

    JMenuItem mntmNutzer = new JMenuItem("Nutzer");
    mntmNutzer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Nutzer iframe = new Nutzer();
                        iframe.setVisible(true);
                        desktopPane.add(iframe);
                        iframe.setSelected(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    mnBearbeiten.add(mntmNutzer);

    JMenuItem mntmRechte = new JMenuItem("Rechte");
    mnBearbeiten.add(mntmRechte);

    JMenu mnNewMenu = new JMenu("New menu");
    mnBearbeiten.add(mnNewMenu);

    JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem);

    JMenuItem mntmNewMenuItem_1 = new JMenuItem("New menu item");
    mnNewMenu.add(mntmNewMenuItem_1);
    desktopPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    desktopPane.setBounds(0, 22, 879, 532);
    frame.getContentPane().add(desktopPane);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar);
```

You should be using:

```
frame.setJMenuBar( menuBar );
```

to add the menubar to a special reserved area of the frame.

Also, don't use a null layout and setBounds(...). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Then you just add the desktop pane to the frame and it will take the space of the frame not taken by the menubar.

Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html). The sections on:

1. `How to Use Menu Bars`
2. `How to use a JDesktopPane`

contain more information and working examples to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
This is all very interesting but unfortunately it does not help me with my problem. The problem is still there.

Comment: @rehti02 This is actually how it's designed

Comment: Okay, but why does it not look like this in any other windows program?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. You have to add this line: `mnNutzer.setRolloverEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

```
JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
```